# How to create thumbnail in node?

Tags: node.js

I know questions about thumbnails have been asked in the past but I can't seem to find an answer that fits exactly what I'm trying to do.

I am using node.js on my window machine and linux on server.  i want to generate thumbnail images.

Anybody can give me idea how to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install the NPM imageMagick package and read its documentation about how to manipulate images.